# Do I need a new EC2 instance for each task/function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Simple example:
If I want to use AWS to host a MySQL database and then use R to pull in data from that MySQL database to analyze, should I have 2 separate instances running? 1 for the database and 1 for R, or can they both be on the same instance?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I think this belongs to ServerFault: this isn't really a code-related question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be both on the same machine, same as if you were running it on your own local machine - if the performance suffers, you can upgrade to increasing larger machines, or eventually split the db of onto its own instance (which is probably best practice anyway), but there is nothing technologically preventing you from using a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on your use case. The ideal way is to always keep your database separately, especially in a private zone. If you keep them in separate instance you can control it in following ways:

1. **R and MySQL in same instance**: This is the easiest way but not recommended for a secure connection.
2. **R and MySQL in different instance in public subnet**: If you keep both isntances in a public subnet, you can still control the traffic through security groups.
3. **R in public subnet and MySQL in private subent**: This is the best practice to keep your database in a private subnet. You can allow access to MySQL instance from R instance and your database is isolated from the the outer world which makes it secure.

If you do not have any enterprise level security constraints, I would suggest going with the second option.